# how to access method?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, composition

I've been playing around inheritance and interface for a little bit and if I have a method with a parameter `SomeClass c` and I use `c.interfaceMethod();` I get an error. How can I access this method `c.interfaceMethod();` if I have a method with a parameter `SomeClass c` like I have here ?

```
public class SomeClass{
    public void someMethod(SomeClass c){

        c.interfaceMethod();      <-- how to access this method?
        //and other methods

        }

}
```

.

```
public class someOtherClass extends SomeClass implements someClassInterface{
    @Override
    public void interfaceMethod(){
        System.out.println("something");

    }
}
```

.

```
public interface someClassInterface{

    public void interfaceMethod();

}
```

Comment: You can't access that method, it isn't declared in `SomeClass`.

Comment: Nothing implements `someClassInterface` and you're trying to access a method that isn't defined in the correct class. Please fix your code sample.

Comment: sorry sorry sorry :( I forgot to put implements as I was typing  this...

Comment: The `implements` is on `someOtherClass`, not on `SomeClass`. `SomeClass` still doesn't declare a `interfaceMethod`.

Comment: @Ris you want to access method of class someOtherClass ??

Comment: `someMethod(SomeClass c)` Can you change type of `c` reference to `someClassInterface` or class that implements this interface like `someOtherClass `?

Comment: @NiksTyagi yes exactly..I know you could do it using someMethod(someOtherClass c) but I'd like to know if you could do it someMethod(SomeClass c)

Comment: Since `SomeClass` doesn't have `interfaceMethod` implemented then compiler can't let you invoke it. You can try casting `SomeClass` to `someClassInterface` and then invoke this method, but this will work only if `c` will be instance of class which implements `someClassInterface` like `someOtherClass`.

Comment: Well I guess I have to use implements in SomeClass...that was my point...

Comment: @Pshemo yeah I wouldnt want to do that...it would be a pain casting it

Comment: Can we know why did you decide to declare `c` as `SomeClass`? If you expect `SomeClass` to have this method add it to your class. If you don't want to implement this method in `SomeClass` then maybe make class and this method `abstract`.

Comment: cause I wanted to have other methods in there from other classes that extend SomeClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want interfaceMethod to be defined on SomeClass, you have to have SomeClass implement SomeClassInterface.  If you only want to implement interfaceMethod in subclasses, you'll have to make SomeClass abstract.

So change your class declaration to:

```
public abstract class SomeClass implements SomeClassInterface {
    ...
}
```

Also, by convention, all class and interface names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: this is what I wanted exactly...thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change like below to access:

```
public class SomeClass{
    public void someMethod(someOtherClass c){

        c.interfaceMethod();      --> to access this method
        //and other methods

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

your class **someClass** is the super class of your class **someOtherClass** so the parent class **"Super class"** does not know any thing about **someOtherClass"SubClass"**
and the method **interfaceMethod()** belongs to someOtherClass  ,it's one of the inheritance fundamentals.
read carefully http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the method `interfaceMethod` of class `someOtherClass` in `SomeClass`.You need to create the object of `someOtherClass` to access it.

Can be updated as below :

```
public class SomeClass{
    public void someMethod(someOtherClass c){

        c.interfaceMethod();     
        //and other methods

        }

}
```

Comment: I know you could do it with public void someMethodsomeOtherClass c but I wanted to see if you could do it with SomeClass c

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `someClassInterface` in `SomeClass` as well

```
public class SomeClass implements someClassInterface {
public void someMethod(SomeClass c){

    c.interfaceMethod();      <-- now you can access this method
    //and other methods

    }

}
```

Comment: do I have to implement someClassInterface in SomeClass or it can be done some other way without having implements someClassInterface

Comment: @Ris, if you need to avoid implementing `someClassInterface`, then you need to declare `interfaceMethod()` inside `SomeClass`, but in this way it will always execute the implemetation insde the new `interfaceMethod()` method in the `SomeClass`. means its a totally deferent method from that one inside `Someinterface`.